TypeError using pandas read_sql_query() with dtype=UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
I'm trying to use Pandas' read_sql_query(), specifying a dtype of UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for one of the columns:
import os
import urllib

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine, exc
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

driver='pyodbc'
driver_version='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
dialect='mssql'
server=os.environ['odbc_server']
database=os.environ['odbc_database']
authentication='ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
username=os.environ['odbc_username']

connection_string = (
    f'{dialect}+{driver}:///?odbc_connect=' +
    urllib.parse.quote_plus(
        f'DRIVER={driver_version};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};' +
        f'UID={username};AUTHENTICATION={authentication};'
    )
)

connection = create_engine(connection_string)

df_ifg_appt = pd.read_sql_query(
    '''
    select
        p.id,
        p.name,
        p.start_date,
        p.end_date
    from core.person p
    ''',
    con=connection,
    dtype={
        'id': UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    }
)

This is giving an error: TypeError: dtype '<class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.UNIQUEIDENTIFIER'>' not understood.
What am I doing wrong?

Well, like the error message says, uniqueidentifier isn't a type supported by pandas. See this question. You'll probably have to treat it like a string, I'm guessing.

This also might be useful.

Thanks. Makes sense. For anyone else reading, possibly helpful to emphasise that things that can be used in to_sql()'s dtype argument can't all be used in read_sql_query()'s dtype argument - the root of my confusion
